# React cookies not being stored in Chrome but are in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I have a cookie I'm trying to set using universal-cookies in a React app. I'm setting it as such:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('test_cookie', true, {
    sameSite: 'none',
    Secure: true,
});
```

I can see it when I do console.log(cookies.cookies):

```
{test_cookie: true}
```

But when I use `cookies.getAll()` and `cookies.get('test_cookie')`, I get `{}`  and `undefined`, respectively. This appears to be only happening in chrome and not firefox (haven't tested safari yet). The App is also run on top of another site, but I thought having `sameSite=None` and `Secure=true` was supposed to resolve this issue.

Comment: Having almost the same problem. I can't read any cookies in Google Chrome but works fine in Firefox. Looking forward the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    cookies.set('test_cookie', 'test_cookie_2', { path: '/' });
    console.log(cookies.get('test_cookie')); // test_cookie_2
```

OR

you can use react-cookie package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie

which is Integrated with universal-cookie & universal-cookie-express

```
    // Root.jsx
    import React from 'react';
    import App from './App';
    import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';
     
    export default function Root() {
      return (
        <CookiesProvider>
          <App />
        </CookiesProvider>
      );
    }
    // App.jsx
    import React from 'react';
    import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
     
    import NameForm from './NameForm';
     
    function App() {
      const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['name']);
     
      function onChange(newName) {
        setCookie('name', newName, { path: '/' });
      }
     
      return (
        <div>
          <NameForm name={cookies.name} onChange={onChange} />
          {cookies.name && <h1>Hello {cookies.name}!</h1>}
        </div>
      );
    }
     
    export default App;
```